# Move all 3 GIMP's windows at the same time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gimp, gnome3

GIMP consists of 3 separate windows. So when I have to move it to another desktop in Ubuntu, I have to move all three separately.

Is there a way to move all 3 at the same time? Right click on GIMP's icon/windows and choosing "Move to Desktop X" does not help as it's icon does not have such option. To add, all others icons have such option.

Comment: Tried from the window menu (up right corner)? That one should have that option.

Comment: @m0skit0 You mean up *left* corner?! When I goes into it I can only see the main GIMP window. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with GNOME3

Comment: Yes, sorry left corner. Sorry, no idea about GNOME3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try moving multiple windows at the same time with a script that use "wmctrl"

However Gimp (next versions) will soon consist of a single window, as I heard from the blogs.

Comment: Great then I'll wait for it :)